# How to Send a File Path to mysql table

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I tired to send this file path

```
    "C:\\Users\\Tesh\\Desktop\\Image - Copy.jpg";
```

but its show like this on mysql database 
         
C:UsersTeshDesktopImage - Copy.jpg"

How Can i Fix this

Comment: How about if you send it like this : `C:/Users/Tesh/Desktop/Image - Copy.jpg`?  Test it and see if it's helps.

Comment: it's called escaping, it can be done by Java or Mysql, print your query before to insert to be sure who is causing the problem. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-literals.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you show us more of your File code so that we can help you? The double backslash (like you've shown) in Java should work, so it's probably something else.

Also, could you try:

```
"C:\\\\Users\\\\Tesh\\\\Desktop\\\\Image - Copy.jpg";
```

or preferably as per @Azad's suggestion:

```
"C:/Users/Tesh/Desktop/Image - Copy.jpg";
```

Comment: +1, however I recommend to use slash(`/`) instead backslashes(\`\\\`) because: **delimiting character is most commonly the slash ("/"), the backslash character ("\"), or colon (":"), though some operating systems may use a different delimiter**
So, maybe this path used on *Unix Os*, the delimiter should be slash(`/`). [See this line](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_%28computing%29)

Comment: @Azad, did you mean to +1 this answer? If so, can you do that please? Actually another thing: this is definitely for Windows, because in his example he specified "C:". So it can't be for UNIX (although you made a valid point).

Comment: Yes, I up vote you first time when you write the answer, it wasn't answer off course, it was a comment, but since you couldn't write comments. But your comment was logical, I saw in you a good background of information, so, now you can comment everywhere, as you have 20+ points, good luck :).